# How to enable Thunderbolt?

Tags: thunderbolt

I have an install of Ubuntu 20.04 and Thunderbolt is not working. I suspect missing packages or something like that but haven't been able to find out what they are.

- machine dual boots Ubuntu and Arch Linux
- in Arch Linux thunderbolt works, providing lan and external displays
- bios Thunderbolt security settings disabled ("none" mode)
- the usb features of my thunderbolt dock are working in Ubuntu, providing keyboard and mouse

The Ubuntu install was generated (from Arch) using `debootstrap`, booting into it and then installing the desktop metapackage using `tasksel` to add the `Ubuntu desktop`. It is running kernel `5.4.0-26-generic`. I expect I am missing something I'd have if I performed a standard install from the iso.

The settings pannel for Thunderbolt says "No Thunderbolt Support" and "Thunderbolt Security level can not be determined"

`bolt` was already installed and running. I also installed `thunderbolt-tools` which made no difference.

What do I need to do to make Thunderbolt work?

Answer (score 5):

*I'll use this answer to record what I've worked out and will update as I progress.*

The kernel modules for Thunderbolt are not included in the kernel package (`linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic` or similar) - there is another package that needs to be installed:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

After a reboot Thunderbolt works and displays connected via a dock become usable; it may be enough to `modprobe` the required modules (I think these are `thunderbolt` and `intel-wmi-thunderbolt`) but I rebooted to be sure.

Current status: After a "power event" (e.g. suspend, disconnecting/reconnecting the dock) my external displays are black. The mouse pointer correctly and visibly tracks across them but nothing else is visible. I've tried reconfiguring via settings panel but it made no difference. I'll update if-and-when I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of it? It shows my display, but it stays black.

Comment: I didn't bother in the end. Arch has everything I need and I prefer its direction to the way Ubuntu is going.